# Adding email into MySQL database with PHP, JQuery, Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My code so far

`main.js` file:

```
$('#addButton').on('click', function() {
  var email = $('#userInput').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'validation.php',
    success: function(html) {
      alert(html); 
    }
  });
});
```

`index.html` file:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" id="userInput"><br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="addButton">Add User</button>
</form>   
<!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```

`validation.php` file:

```
    <?php

     if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) {

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_username", "my_password", "my_db");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
      die("Error Connecting To Database");
    }

    if (validateEmail($_POST['email'])) {
      $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."')";

      if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        $success = "Email: ".$_POST['email']." added";
      } else {
        echo "Error in query";
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Here is my validate email function:

```
    function validateEmail($email) {
    if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]+)@([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]{2,})(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $email)) {
      echo "Invalid Email";
      return false;
    } else {
      $domain = array('umich.edu');
      list(, $user_domain) = explode('@', $email, 2);
      return in_array($user_domain, $domain);
    }
  }
```

Am I performing my Ajax request incorrectly because it never adds the email to the database?

Comment: You need to pass email value from your ajax request as `data: { email: email },`

Comment: yes u missed to passing the data data: {email : email},

Answer (score 0):

Try something this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    // make sure you respect the same origin policy with this url:
    url: 'validation.php',
    data: { 
        'email': email
    },
    success: function(html){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way to do that, but I think this is the best way and the easiest way for you to make it work base on your current code.

First thing, You don't need to use `type="submit"` button when using AJAX.

HTML should be,

```
<form id='emailform'>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" id="userInput"><br>
  <button type="button" name="submit" id="addButton">Add User</button>
</form>
```

Your JS should be something like this, use jQuery's `.serialize()` function to your form:

```
$('#addButton').on('click', function() {
  var email = $('#userInput').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'validation.php',
    data: $('#emailform').serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html) {
      alert(html); 
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function also in your main.js.
Please remember that whenever you run any post request and if you want to send some data to server you need to mention that variable or json one of the parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp", {email: "hello@hello.com"},
      function(data, status){
        alert("Data sent!");
    });
  });
});
```

Or you can use the below code also for better understanding

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  // make sure you respect the same origin policy with this url:
  url: 'validation.php',
  data: { 
    email: email
  },
  contentType:'application/json',
  success: function(html){
  }
});
```

Comment: Your welcome If my answer helped you please mark answer as accepted below up-down arrow. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for correcting it should be ContentType(Input Type) and dataType (for response)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
$('#addButton').on('click', function(event){
  /* prevent default behavior of form submission.  */
  event.preventDefault();

  var email = $('#userInput').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: {
      email: email,
      submit: 1
    },
    url: "validation.php",
    success: function(html){
      alert(html);
    }
  });
});
```

You need to send `email` and `submit` because you wrapped all code in `if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) {` means you are checking if the `submit` field submitted or not.

Comment: Since I have my files split up like, index.html, validation.php and main.js. Do I need to change index.html to index.php and include the validation.php file?

Comment: @CharlesRoth update this code in `main.js` and you don't set form action so form will submitted on same url update `index.html` to `index.php` and include `validation.php` in `index.php` in before form;